# Randomly unable to hit my APIs on 1 phone

Tags: android

I'm having an issue that is becoming increasingly annoying and I'm not sure what I can do about it.

I have a web site running and a subdomain of that which my APIs hit.  The phone I'm using for testing (it is another person's phone) is an Epic 4G on the Sprint network.  It is running Android 2.2.1.

Quite frequently, my Android app will become unable to hit my API over the Sprint network on this phone.  Any calls to my API return UnknownHostException.  Hitting any website in Browser (ex: www.google.com) works with no problem.  Turning on wifi and hitting the API works fine.

After some time (this morning, about 30 minutes), it will start being able to connect again on the Sprint network.  But now it doesn't work over wifi!  When I turn wifi on and hit the API, I receive an org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException error (Connect to my API refused).  Again, every other phone running my app can hit the API over network or wifi with no problem.

Here's the thing:  None of the other phones running my App have this problem.  In fact, a friend of mine has an Epic 4G on the Sprint network, too, and he's never had the issue.  I even called him a moment ago and asked him to use my app to hit my API while this issue was happening to me and he successfully hit the API.  That tells me it's something with the phone, but I've no idea what.

I'm looking for ideas as to why this is an issue. Ultimately, how I can handle it, but I'm not sure I can really do anything.  It sounds like there may be some kind of connection profile happening behind the scenes and it is obviously very flawed.  Is there some way I can turn it off?  Is there some way I can get my app to clear my API url from this presumed cache upon a connection failure?

Comment: could you write your "update" as an answer and accept them? Its always good to see in the search result if a question as an accepted answer.

Comment: Sure. I couldn't do it at the time because there's a wait period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Android is not flushing the DNS cache when you toggle wifi on and off in 2.2. I've had the server reconfigured to always return the external address whether you're hitting it remotely or on the server's network and it seems to be working fine now.